# How to update libstdc++6

Tags: apt

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 and need to install passenger module. A command `sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-passenger` tells

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-passenger : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to use `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6` or `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12`

But first tells that I already have lib and second tells that such version is not found.

How could I execute command `sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-passenger`?

Comment: Looks like messed up repositories. Please provide your sources list

Comment: Started to reinstall system, after apt-get -f install crush

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libapache2-mod-passenger shows the message is correct for 16.04, why do you have a 14.04 package appearing?  I agree with fkraiem